# How do I prevent users from deleting messages and changing the settings of Thunderbird?

Tags: permissions, email, thunderbird

How can I prevent a user from deleting messages and changing the settings of Thunderbird?

I don't want users to be able to delete any messages or change the settings of Thunderbird: only an administrator should be able to change anything in Thunderbird.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that there is no trivial way to prevent deletion of messages. But you can lock user pref (and all Thunderbird's settings), see: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences