# Installation directory of thunderbird

Tags: installation, thunderbird, directory

I want to lock the settings to use by user so that i find my thunderbird installation directory but i couldn't. please help me and tell me the installation directory of thunderbird in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to lock the settings to use by user`? The Thunderbird settings are saved in each user's home folder under the `.thunderbird` folder

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/307237/how-to-prevent-a-user-from-deleting-messages-and-changing-the-settings-of-thunde

Answer (score 1):

To personalize the settings of Mozilla family [use profiles](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/profiles). [Here](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/using-multiple-profiles) how to use different profiles.

And if you want where exactly profiles are stored, They are in `~/.thunderbird/<Profile name>/` as [mozilla messaging support says](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Linux_and_Unix). Of course in fact the profile is stored in 
`~/.thunderbird/<some characters>.<Profile name>/`. they are some random 8 characters before the profile name which thunderbird chooses. you can access the profile folder by just use `cd ~/.thunderbird/*<Profile name>/`.

If you just want to know where is the executable file of Thunderbird. use the command `whereis thunderbird`.

Comment: In fact they are located at `~/.thunderbird/<Profile name>/`

Comment: You are right. I have corrected the location.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the terminal by Ctrl + Alt + T and just type this command:

```
 cd /home/yourusername/.thunderbird/user.default/
```

You will find the user's Thunderbird directory there.
And for locking the the settings you may look at Qasim's [reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307237/how-to-prevent-a-user-from-deleting-messages-and-changing-the-settings-of-thunde).